# Unable to type in text input in Firefox & IExplorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a basic registration form on my website. While testing it in different browsers I noticed that it was fully functioning in Chrome but not in Firefox or IExplorer.
In both Firefox and Iexplorer I'm unable to type in any of the input fields.
I don't know what's causing it and I'm not getting any errors.

[Here's the page.](http://nolink.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually CAN type in the fields, you just can't see the text because the padding and height inside the text boxes are pushing the text around inside the text box, moving it outside the visible area of the input field.

The following will remove the unnecessary vertical padding:

```
#registration input, #registration textarea {
    /* Your other properties */
    padding: 0px 8px;
}
```

Comment: No problem. I should also note that on line 53 of your HTML there is an unmatched `<ul>` tag (looks like it should be a closing tag, and you just forgot the `/` )

Comment: If my answer solved your issue satisfactorily, consider accepting it :)